# How do I add <b> (for bolding font) to part of text inside string interpolation for sns message?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to take a string in this format `I am a level ${level} coder`, where ${level} will be some value passed in. But I want only specific word in this sentence bolded. So lets say in this example I want "level" and "coder" bolded. How do I achieve this?

Current Behavior:

Even if I do `<b>` or `<strong>` inside  ``` `` ``` the tags just get converted to string. It doesn't actually bold the text for me.

Update: This is exactly what I am doing with aws sns. But I want to achieve this with string interpolation.

```js
let snsData = {
  Message: < strong > "This is an automated message" < /strong> + '\n' +
  "You have successfully uploaded the following:" + '\n'
  `File name: ${snsFileName}\n
            Number of lines: ${numberOfLines}\n
      If there are any issues, please contact XXX for assistance.`,
  Subject: 'Successfully Uploaded to XX',
  TopicArn: 'XXXXX'
};
```

Comment: `I am a level <b> ${level} coder </b>` ?

Comment: ^^^ what he said, except semantic correction would be use `<strong>` instead of `<b>`

Comment: @RobertHarvey If i do this within `I am a level <b> ${level} coder </b>` it puts the b tags as a string, it doesn't actually bold the text for me. This is what i am having problem with

Comment: Then we need to see more of your code.

Comment: @ChrisW. if I put this inside ` ` it just makes the entire thing a string except the variable passed in

Comment: In *React.js* project I faced similar problem. Soluton was property `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Maybe you should search for similat solution.

Comment: Ya, would need an example of the instance to reproduce since it's currently not as expected as given by example in answer below.

Comment: @ChrisW I added update with code I am trying to achieve this with, please see above

Answer (score 0):

Addendum, so this is entirely unique to your instance and I suggest better familiarizing yourself with how string / interpolation and objects work but for the sake of learning, cheers;

```js
const $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id) },
      level = 'expert',
      str = `I am a level <strong>${level} coder</strong>`,
      snsFileName = 'testFileNameBlah',
      numberOfLines = 99,
      snsData = {
        Message: '<strong>This is an automated message</strong><br/>' +
                 'You have successfully uploaded the following:<br/>' +
                 `File name: <strong>${snsFileName}</strong><br/>
                  Number of lines: <strong>${numberOfLines}</strong><br/>` +
                 'If there are any issues, please contact XXX for assistance.<br/>',
        Subject: 'Successfully Uploaded to XX',
        TopicArn: 'XXXXX'
      };

$('blah').innerHTML = str + '<hr>';

$('fixme').innerHTML = snsData.Message + snsData.Subject;
```

```html
<span id="blah"></span>

<h2>Addendum</h2>
<p id="fixme"></p>
```